# Is the Nyquist rate independent of the power of the analog signal being digitized?

Tags: dsp

In analog-to-digital conversion, how independent is the Nyquist rate from the power of the signal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Completely independent. It is dependent on frequency only. The amplitude of the signal is only relevant when looking at the number of bits used (and the dynamic range).

[See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Theoretically, the rate is independant.

In reality, exceeding certain power levels will cause real world digitizers to increase in non-linearities (clipping, saturation, thermal damage, and etc.), which will introduce harmonics and other spectra above any Nyquist rate based on linear system assumptions, if not complete system failure.